# How to auto mount NFS shares on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, automount, nfs

I need to mount at boot time the equivalent of the line command :

```
sudo mount -o rw,bg,hard,resvport,intr,noac,nfc,tcp mymachine:/var/logs /Volumes/logs
```

…and I have no idea about how to do it on Mac (OS X 10.9 Mavericks)

```
bash-3.2$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HD                      499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HD2                     499.8 GB   disk1s2
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *668.2 MB   disk2
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS OSXDocsetCD             668.1 MB   disk2s2
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *477.6 MB   disk3
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS DevToolsDocsetCD        477.6 MB   disk3s2
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *596.2 MB   disk4
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk4s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS iOSDocsetCD             596.1 MB   disk4s2
```

Comment: @Robuust - I added the information about diskutil above as I was not able to reply here ... I hope it is fine ..

Comment: I'm not sure but this article might help you out: http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/04/automatically-connect-to-network-drive-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

Using autofs, as suggested by others is probably the way to go. Most of what follows works in El Capitan, which made auto mounting more difficult, but it should apply to Mavericks too. I do not have a Mavericks system to test.

In order to make this work edit /etc/auto_master and add the following line:

`/-          auto_nfs    -nobrowse,nosuid`

Then create a new file `/etc/auto_nfs` (with permissions 644) with the following content:

`/../Volumes/logs -fstype=nfs,nrw,bg,hard,resvport,intr,noac,nfc,tcp mymachine:/var/logs`

You have to add the `/..` in front of the `/Volumes`, because Mac OS X (at least El Capitan will try to prevent you from mounting thing in `/Volumes` and `/../Volumes` is still `/Volumes`, it just tricks the filter. This might not be necessary for Mavericks)

Then start the auto mount daemon

`sudo automount -cv`

and you should see that the volume has been mounted (`ls /Volumes/logs`)

Answer (score 0):

Open system preferences -> users and there you can choose login items

You can either save your command in a file: 
Open textedit
Name the new file something.sh
Make the first line: #!/bin/bash
Then add your code
 run chmod +x on it
add it to login items

Or I think you could drag the mounted drive into login items, I haven't tested it tho

Comment: This might work. Also, try Googling `launchctl`.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for... 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/auto_master.5.html

Comment: Please add more information on what your URL is pointing to. The URL might die, leaving your answer useless.

Answer (score -1):

Check out `/etc/auto_master`.
There is an automount tool running for exactly this purpose. [It seems to be disable on Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120385/how-to-automatically-mount-nfs-shares-on-os-x), but you can just turn it on.